(Debugger Unbound breakpoint) I am working on nest application in nx workspace
I encountered a problem with my Nest.js application's large Docker image, which led me to add "production": { "generatePackageJson": true } in my project.json file. However, this caused an error that was only resolved after updating my nx (to 18.0.7) and nx/weback (to 19.1.1) versions.
Now, my debugger isn't working properly. It successfully attaches to the server, but all breakpoints are unbound. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?
here is my launhe.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to nestjs",
      "request": "attach",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/api",
      "type": "node",
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}


I tried multiple different configration for the launch.json and none of them works, Also I have sourceMap: true in tsconfig
